# display my popup into other websites through embedded code

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have developed a discussion popup on my website , now I want my customers to use it on their website, so they just copy the code from their dashboard on my website and embed that code into their websites so the discussion popup from my website load into their website so all the comments and data from my system load into there so they could submit comments and replies through this popup into my system ,

I am not a javascript expert , but I have seen lots of providers do this like facebook allow u to add their messanger chat popup into your website so your customers can chat with you, i'm in facebook place now and would like to have my users implement my popup into their website so they could use my comments service and connect with their customers, hope this is clear enough

**EDIT**

This could be something like this chat popup in this pic, as you see, the chat popup is loaded from a third party website into the website below , so the website owner can connect with their customers through this chat popup connected the provder's system.

[image]

I have tried to do this with in Iframe , but if u actually use this code into your website u will get what i mean , the iframe will restrict other content even if the popup is closed , so I thought there might be another solution

```
<iframe src="http://dev.zedmanager.com/test_pop" style="
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 999999;
height: 100%;
"> </iframe>
```

Comment: This will not work as you described it. You can definitely share code that they can use, yet the data will have to come from an API or one resource that multiple sites can reach to to get the same data.

Comment: I have just added s an edit , could u please look into it ? you probably missunderstood me , as this feature has been done before , but i'm not sure how it is done , I was thinking of using Iframe ? but I am not sure how it should be used into their website as the iframe will defensibly restrict other content as it should be filing the full page  even with the popup closed

Comment: As you might have eluded to, iFrames and other embedded code will often be subject to CORS. Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS This will prevent them from running Scripts or connecting to other resources.

Comment: I think this will load the whole page into the website , yes elements will be separated and no restriction, but also the resources like css files will affect the other website... which is not a good idea , that's why I think it should remain in iframe better, the case is loading the iframe will restrict other content